# append sequences from matching lines over a file using awk (or python)?

Tags: python, awk, sed

I am trying to concatenate all gene sequences from a file for each individual and think there might be a way to do this with a oneliner using awk or sed.

Say I have a file with ID names (Mex1, Can2, etc) and sequence (TGAC...), and each line has a different ID, gene (A, B), and sequence.

```
Mex1_A TGACTT
Mex2_A TGACTA
CAN2_A TCGGGG
CAN4_A TCGACG
Mex1_B TCGGCA
Mex2_B TCGCCC
CAN2_B TCTACT
CAN4_B TCTACC
```

Is there a way to append the sequences from each ID that match, concatenating all sequence data for each individual in one line e.g.:

```
Mex1 TGACTTTCGGCA
Mex2 TGACTATCGCCC
CAN2 TCGGGGTCTACT
CAN4 TCGACGTCTACC
```

Is this possible using those editors? Perhaps it would best be done in perl/python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk -F'[_ ]' '{a[$1] = a[$1] $3} END{for (i in a) print i, a[i]}' file
CAN4 TCGACGTCTACC
Mex1 TGACTTTCGGCA
Mex2 TGACTATCGCCC
CAN2 TCGGGGTCTACT
```

Comment: Looks like someone was after the [badge](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1108/vox-populi)

Comment: idk, I seem to have been experiencing a drive-by downvoter the past few days. I'll add it to my list of things to worry about right under whether or not a Kardashian will be blonde this week.

Comment: Great. @Ed Morton, could you explain briefly what the components of that one-liner are?

Comment: Sure but it's all very basic awk so you might get more out of it if YOU tell ME what you think it's doing and ask me if there's a part you don't understand? The necessary reference material: http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Field-Splitting-Summary, http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Arrays, http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Reference-to-Elements, http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#BEGIN_002fEND,